# How to load R libraries from R_LIBS_USER in plr (PostgreSQL R extension )

Tags: r, postgresql

I 've installed several libraries in `$R_LIBS_USER`. Unfortunately, all these libraries couldn't load in `PL/R`. It seems that I can only load libraries in `$R_LIBS_SITE`.

Is it possible that I can directly use the libraries in `$R_LIBS_USER` with some configuration of `PL/R`?

The Logged-in User of PostgreSQL is my current user, which has been granted as super user. Here is the result of `SELECT * FROM plr_environ();`:

```
 PG_GRANDPARENT_PID | 29232
 PWD                | /var/lib/postgresql
 PGLOCALEDIR        | /usr/share/locale
 LANG               | en_US.UTF-8
 PGSYSCONFDIR       | /etc/postgresql-common
 SHLVL              | 1
 PGDATA             | /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
 _                  | /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres
 LC_COLLATE         | en_US.UTF-8
 LC_CTYPE           | en_US.UTF-8
 LC_MESSAGES        | en_US.UTF-8
 LC_MONETARY        | C
 LC_NUMERIC         | C
 LC_TIME            | C
 R_HOME             | /usr/lib/R
 R_PLATFORM         | x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 R_PAPERSIZE_USER   | a4
 R_PAPERSIZE        | letter
 R_PRINTCMD         | /usr/bin/lpr
 R_RD4PDF           | times,inconsolata,hyper
 R_TEXI2DVICMD      | /usr/bin/texi2dvi
 R_GZIPCMD          | /bin/gzip
 R_UNZIPCMD         | /usr/bin/unzip
 R_ZIPCMD           | /usr/bin/zip
 R_BZIPCMD          | /bin/bzip2
 R_BROWSER          | xdg-open
 EDITOR             | vi
 PAGER              | /usr/bin/pager
 R_PDFVIEWER        | /usr/bin/xdg-open
 LN_S               | ln -s
 MAKE               | make
 SED                | /bin/sed
 TAR                | /bin/tar
 R_SYSTEM_ABI       | linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?
 R_LIBS_USER        | ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2
 R_LIBS_SITE        | /usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library
 R_SESSION_TMPDIR   | /tmp/RtmpB5KlAx
(37 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution can temporarily set the search path of lib.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION r_libpaths()  RETURNS text[] AS ' .libPaths(‘xxxxx’)
'  LANGUAGE  plr;
select r_libpaths();
```

Here, 'xxx' is the new path of library. Any suggestion permanently modifying it will be welcomed.

It worked at my laptop but failed again at my virtual machine in the company. I will paste the sessioninfo of this environment later.

I finally found the reason that my home directory has no read permission right for other users. It could be fixed by *chmod* command. Then, PL/R can load libraries from R_LIBS_USER.